# "SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal" using 'r' prefix

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I'm having this issue with the following Python piece of code:

```
TTT_PATH = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\'
```

Comment: It doesn't like the trailing backslash - can you do without it? Alternatively, see https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-can-t-raw-strings-r-strings-end-with-a-backslash

Comment: @tobias_k see the Python FAQ I've linked, you can't have an odd number of trailing backslashes *even in a raw string*

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah, sorry, asked before reading the link...

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the last \ like this:

```
TTT_PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\\'
```